# How to identify two-name cases in a list that could have up to four names

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This question is an offshoot of an earlier question: [Excel Formula - name separation formula for people that have multi-part last names:](https://superuser.com/q/1452912/364367).

**Context**

I have a list of over 20,000 contacts where there is one single "Full Name" column.  I need to create two columns for the First Name & Last Name.  However, the names do not all fit that simple pattern.  The list includes names like:

```
David Batte
Guy-Mael Jacobe de Naurois
Jean-Marc Lioutier
Thibaud Le Seguillon
Mrs. Manuela Junghaehnel
Hussain Mohammed Dipu Kabir
```

As a result of the earlier question, I am attacking the problem by peeling off collections of names that fit particular patterns to which I can apply appropriate parsing rules.  A relatively small number of patterns will allow me to automate parsing of most of the list, making the remainder a more manageable task.

**This question**

A substantial portion of the full name list contains just a first and last name, which are easy to parse.  My objective with this question is to identify those two-name names so they can be separated from the rest of the list.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to identify cases where names in a list contain just two component names, like first and last name.  That condition is defined by the spaces that separate the component names.

**Method 1**

This question is an offshoot of an earlier one ([Excel Formula - name separation formula for people that have multi-part last names:](https://superuser.com/q/1452912/364367)), where we already discussed in comments identifying cases of a single name, like just first or last name.  If you have already removed those names from the list, so every entry is guaranteed to have at least two names, you can use a similar technique here and build on it.

This approach looks for a space, then starting from there, looks for another space.  If it can find a second space, the entry has more than two component names.  If the entry is in A1, the basic formula would be:

```
=FIND(" ",TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1))+1)
```

The result of this will be either a number (location of the next space), or a #VALUE! error if there isn't one.  The #VALUE! error will be easy to spot and identifies two-name entries.  Note that it will also identify single name entries, which is why this method will only work if you have already removed those.

You can make this more visually appealing by testing the result for the error condition, and then displaying either a text message for the two-name cases or a blank.  Wrapping the formula above in an IF test would give you a formula like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1))+1)),"Just 2","")
```

**Method 2**

Another approach is to count the spaces.  You could actually use this approach to find any specific number of spaces, so just changing the target count would let you find the single-name entries also.  This approach counts spaces by eliminating all of the spaces and seeing how many characters the string shrinks.  The length comparison produces the count of spaces.  You wrap that with an IF test to do what you want with the resulting number.  The formula for flagging two-name entries (i.e., single space), would look like this:

```
=IF(LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",""))=1,"Just 2","")
```

Comment: Method 1 is working properly,,, but have some issue with Method 2 formula,, +10 ☺

Comment: ,, earlier was returning SPACE instead of Count but since I've adjusted `""` with `" "` ,, working properly!!

Comment: doesn't method 2 work better as just `LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",""))+1` to tell you how many names you've got?

Comment: @AlexM, you're right if that was the goal. The OP didn't fully describe the objective here (it's an offshoot of another question). There's a master list of full names; objective is to parse that into firstname & lastname. Some names aren't that simple (names with prefixes, initials, titles, multiple last names, etc.). So they need to peel off names that fit different patterns to apply different kinds of parsing solutions. The goal in this question is to identify simple 2-name names which are trivial to parse.  The count of names beyond that isn't really helpful for identifying parsing rules.

Comment: fixer1234... This has helped me out so so much! thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave a simpler method which *may not be optimum* for 20000 rows.

- Split the names by spaces using Data -> Text to Columns
- The names will be split over four columns A, B, C & D
- click on filter and filter for `blanks` in column C
- you will have only the two word names showing in A and B. copy them across.
- you can join the names using `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1:B1)`

Comment: So simple nobody thought of it.  You could also filter on col B blank to hide single names.  It might be worth noting that the text to columns could be specified to another output column, or they could work with a copy of the column, to retain the original data.  Actually, the OP wouldn't even need the last step.  The purpose of the exercise was to isolate those names so they could be parsed into two columns.  This leaves the parsing already done.

Comment: Great starting point. Just watch out for "Mr Smith" - is that a two-name entry? Or only one "Name" and a "prefix"? Depends on the context as to whether the distinction matters

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest two possible methods, first is Non VBA and others is VBA.*

**Method 1:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter this Formula in Cell `H2` to create helper values (*Identify parts of names*) and fill it down.

`=LEN(G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2," ",""))`

- Write Criteria `2` in cell `H1`.
- Enter this Array Formula in Cell `I2`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill it down.

  `{=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$G$14,SMALL(IF(H$1=$H$2:$H$14,ROW($G$2:$G$14)- MIN(ROW($G$2:$G$14))+1,""), ROW()-1)),"")}`

**N.B.**

- By changing criteria in Cell `H1` to `1` or `3` you can get list of two and more than 3 parts names.

[image]

---

[image]

---

**Method 2:**

*Since you are dealing with more that 20000 rows then VBA (Macro) will be the fastest method to finish the job.*

**How it works:**

- **Right Click** Sheet Tab & from poped up menu hit **View code** to get VB editor.
- **Copy & Paste** this code as standard module, and finally **RUN** the Macro.

  ```
  Sub DeleteMorethan2()

  Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, space_count As Integer

  For r = 2 To 15
  space_count = 0

  For c = 1 To Len(Range("A" & r))

     If Mid(Range("A" & r), c, 1) = " " Then space_count = space_count + 1
     If space_count > 1 Then Range("A" & r).ClearContents

    Next
  Next

  End Sub
  ```

---

*You get this:*

[image]

**N.B.**

- This Code is working on `Rows 2 to 15` and by editing this part `For r = 2 To 15`, you can include more Rows.
- The used Column is `A`, which is also editable.

**Additionally, I would like to suggest an Array formula to re-create the name list by removing blank rows.**

[image]

- Enter this Array Formula in Cell `B2`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill it down.

  `{=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$14,SMALL(IF(A$2:A$14<>"",ROW(A$2:A$14)-ROW(A$2)+1),ROWS(B$2:B2))),"")}`

**Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95479/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-fixer1234).